# How to display iOS app's deep links on email as links

Tags: ios, email, react-native, deep-linking

I'm using [deep linking](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) for my `react-native` app to let user click on a link to open my app and perform some actions.

My problem here is when I send email (using `<a href="">` tags and send the body as HTML) to user with these deep links (e.g `myapp://profile?userId=123456`), they are recognized as **text** instead of **links** by email clients, so at the moment my app users can't press on the "links" to open the app.

Comment: Send HTML email with explicit `<a href="">` tags?

Comment: Yes @ceejayoz, I was using email with explicit <a href=""> tag and sending the email body as HTML. Edited the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did some research and it turns out email clients like **Gmail** don't like links with abnormal protocol such as `myapp://` and they will strip out those links from `href` attribute. My solution is to use another link which will eventually redirect the user to the deep link, for example: `https://api.myapp.com/redirect?url={encoded-deep-link}`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with your app but the issue is with the email client which sends the email as a plain text. Many clients don't send custom html code as an email. Thunderbird can send it though.