# href is not recognized in email

Tags: html, react-native, url, href, strapi

I am trying to send a reset-password link to users email when they click forgot password in react-native app. The email is sent from Strapi using email template and includes the following code:

```
<p>click to reset password</p>
<a href="app://ResetPassword/<%= TOKEN %>">Reset password</a>
```

The problem is that the link is not clickable in the email apps on either android nor ios. It just shows as text. However, when inspecting, the code in the email looks like:

```
<p>click to reset password</p>
<a href=3D"app://ResetPassword/sometokenthatislong">Reset password</a>
```

Is the problem the href url or is it a problem within the email providers that they don't support that kind of url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display iOS app's deep links on email as links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037786/how-to-display-ios-apps-deep-links-on-email-as-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question and the solution is that "deep-links" are not widely supported in email providers. The solution is to use redirect using a normal link. For further reading see:

[How to display iOS app's deep links on email as links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037786/how-to-display-ios-apps-deep-links-on-email-as-links)

Comment: If there is another question on SO that has answers that can answer this question, you should flag this post as duplicate and provide that question there, or comment on OP's question this as a suggestion.