# MAUI IOS App universal links don't open my application

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, maui

I am trying to start my MAUI IOS App using URI, but when I clicked on URL that must open my app nothing happen. I set a breakpoint into OpenUrl and ContinueUserActivity to check if its called, but its never called.

I created apple-app-site-association :

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "H9375ODJ26.com.example.testapp",
                "paths": [ "/video/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the file is accessible on https://www.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and it has content-type = application/json.

I have added in my Entitlements.plist this code:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:example.com</string>
</array>
```

In developer.apple.com Associated domains option for my app is turned on.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing ? I expect when I click on the URI, a pop-up will appear asking how to open the uri - browser or my ios app.

Comment: *" I clicked on URL"* * link is on some website, that you click in Safari? (not in your app) * Testing on actual device? (not emulator - not sure if this matters, just exploring possibilities)

Comment: I simulate that I receive some url by email, I clicke on URL and link leads to a video that is uploaded to my web application, I want to be able to choose which app to open the video.

Comment: Maybe an issue with email client. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113778/199364).

Comment: Testing universal links on simulator or device can be done a) by sending a URL via email and opening it on the device or b) by sending a URL to yourself in the Messages app and opening it there. Opening the URL in Safari (by typing it in, for example) does not work.

Comment: I am not trying to open my app by typing url in Safari. I am trying to test universal links on device by sending  a url via emal and Skype, but when I click the link it opens in Safari, not asking me how to open.

Answer (score 0):

In Maui you can use Launcher to open other applications through URI. Apple requires that you define the schemes you want to use. Add the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key and schemes to the Info.plist files:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>  
<array>  
    <string>XXX</string>   
</array>
```

Call the ILauncher.OpenAsync method and pass in a String or Uri representing the application to open：

```
await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("xxx");
```

For more details, refer to：[Launcher | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)

Comment: Launcher is used to open applications from another application. I want to open my app when I click the url when sent to me via email or Skype for example.

Comment: You can try changing your path to [*] .